# How to dynamically send multiple image values?

Tags: php, html

HTML code like this :

```
<form action="upload_multiple_post.php" method="post">
    <input type='file' name="images[]" id="upload-file" multiple />
    <?php
        for($i=0;$i<5; $i++) {
    ?>
        <div class="img-container" id="box<?php echo $i ?>">
            <button  style="display: none;" type="button" class="btn btn-primary show-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <input name="mySubmit" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

upload_multiple_post like this :

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';die();
?>
```

Demo and full code like this : http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7623-agw4

For example I chose 2 pictures, then I choose 2 more pictures again. Then I click submit button, the image successfully sent only 2 last picture

There should be 4 images successfully sent

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: `multiple` attribute means that you can use multiple elements per browse/time , closing the browse dialog and re-opening it will override your selections, otherwise you can use javascript to store your choices

Comment: @hassan, Maybe you can answer this question with the code. Eg using phpfiddle or something else. Let me understand what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated by @hassan in his comment earlier - you cannot expect a simple HTML file element to remember previous selections when you open the file browse dialog multiple times. In order to accomplish the desired effect you would need to utilise javascript to store references to all the files selected.

The following code should give you plenty of useful ideas - you could pretty much run this "as is" with only minor edits to local filesystem paths.

The example also shows a rudimentary way to use "drag & drop" to upload files as well as displaying a preview of files selected. Hope you can make use of the code.

Note: The use of `enctype='multipart/form-data'` when using the methods here ( namely trying to capture `php://input` ) will cause it to fail. As the form is not being submitted in a standard manner there is no need to include that - nor the form action as that is specified by the ajax function.

```
<?php
    /* you could handle the file upload here rather than a separate script */
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        $filename = isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] ) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FILENAME'] : false;

        if( $filename ){

            $dir = 'c:/temp/fileuploads/';
            $path = $dir . $filename;

            /* create a new file with the contents sent via xhr */
            $bytes = file_put_contents( $path, file_get_contents( 'php://input' ) );

            /* send feedback to client if required */
            echo json_encode( array( 'filename'=>$filename, 'path'=>$path, 'bytes'=>$bytes ) );
        }

        exit();
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Example File upload - multiple selections</title>
        <style type='text/css'>

            html *{font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;font-size:1rem;box-sizing:border-box;}
            form{width:75%;float:none;margin:1rem auto;border:1px solid black;padding:1rem;}
            #dropzone{padding:1rem;margin:1rem auto;float:none;width:60%;height:250px;border:3px solid green;text-align:center;line-height:200px;}
            #previews{margin:2rem auto;float:none;width:90%;}
            #previews img{margin:0.1rem;}
            #list{margin:2rem auto;float:none;width:90%;}
            input[type='file']{width:90%;}
            input[type='button']{background:steelblue;color:white;}
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var size=150;
            var oImages=[];
            var uploadtarget = '';

            /* Simple ajax file upload function */
            function uploadhandler( url,obj ){
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if ( xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200 ) {

                        var json=JSON.parse( this.response );
                        var li=document.createElement('li');
                            li.innerHTML=' -> uploaded: '+json.filename;
                        document.getElementById('list').appendChild( li );
                    }
                };
                xhr.open('POST',url,true);
                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined-binary');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('x_filename',obj.name);
                xhr.send( obj.file );
            }

            function getaspect(w,h){
                if( w==h )return 1;
                else if( w > h ) return 2;
                else if( h > w ) return 3;
                else return 4;
            }
            function getratio(w,h){
                return parseFloat(w) / parseFloat(h);
            }

            function bindEvents(){

                var oFiles=document.getElementById('usrfile');
                var oBttn=document.getElementById('upload');
                var oPreview=document.getElementById('previews');
                var oList=document.getElementById('list');
                var oDrop=document.getElementById('dropzone');



                oFiles.addEventListener('change', function(e){
                    var files=this.files;
                    for( var i=0; i < files.length; i++ ){

                        /* Get a reference to the file */
                        var file=files.item( i );

                        /* store properties of selected file(s) though only 2 are required */
                        var obj={
                            'file':file,
                            'name':file.name,
                            'size':file.size,
                            'lastModified':file.lastModified,
                            'lastModifiedDate':file.lastModifiedDate,
                            'type':file.type
                        };
                        oImages.push( obj );

                        /* add new list item to show selected file(s) */
                        var li=document.createElement('li');
                            li.innerHTML=file.name;

                        oList.appendChild( li );
                    }
                }.bind( oFiles ),false);


                oBttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
                    oImages.forEach(function( obj ){
                        try{
                            var mime = /^image\//;
                            if ( !mime.test( obj.type ) ) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            /* Show a preview */
                            var img = document.createElement('img');
                                img.file=obj.file;
                                img.onload=function(event){

                                    var ratio=getratio( this.width,this.height );

                                    switch( getaspect( this.width, this.height ) ){
                                        case 1:
                                            this.width=size;
                                            this.height=size;
                                        break;
                                        case 2:
                                            this.width=size;
                                            this.height=size / ratio;
                                        break;
                                        case 3:
                                            this.height=size;
                                            this.width=size * ratio;
                                        break;
                                        case 4:

                                        break;
                                    }
                                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL( this.src );
                                };

                            /* add new thumbnail to the DOM */
                            oPreview.appendChild( img );

                            /* */
                            var reader = new FileReader();
                                reader.onload = (function(a) { return function(e) { a.src = e.target.result; }; })( img );
                                reader.readAsDataURL( obj.file );

                            /* upload the file */
                            uploadhandler.call( this, uploadtarget, obj );
                        }catch( err ){

                        }
                    });
                    oImages=[];
                },false );



                var dragenter=function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    console.log(e.type);
                };

                var dragdrop=function(e){
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var filelist=e.dataTransfer.files

                    for( var i=0; i < filelist.length; i++ ){
                        /* Get a reference to the file */
                        var file=filelist.item( i );

                        /* store properties of selected file(s) though only 2 are required */
                        var obj={
                            'file':file,
                            'name':file.name,
                            'size':file.size,
                            'lastModified':file.lastModified,
                            'lastModifiedDate':file.lastModifiedDate,
                            'type':file.type
                        };
                        oImages.push( obj );

                        var li=document.createElement('li');
                            li.innerHTML=file.name;

                        oList.appendChild( li );
                    }
                };

                /* drag & drop event listeners */
                oDrop.addEventListener('dragover',dragenter,false);
                oDrop.addEventListener('dragenter',dragenter,false);
                oDrop.addEventListener('drop',dragdrop,false);
            }


            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',bindEvents,false);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='file' name='images[]' id='usrfile' multiple />
            <input name='bttn' id='upload' type='button' value='Upload' />
            <div id='dropzone'>Drag & Drop files here</div>
            <ul id='list'></ul>
            <div id='previews'></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Btw, Is it like my case, can it be done? My case, any images can be deleted or edited

Comment: I had try it. But it does not work. I add `<input name='sumbit' id='upload' type='submit' value='Sumbit' />` and I add `echo '<pre>';print_r($_POST);echo '</pre>';die();`. It's the same. You try answer my question as per my case

Comment: The button should no longer be a `submit` element - because this use javascript we want to trigger a javascript function when the button is clicked - NOT submit the form in the traditional sense.

Comment: Where the button used for send and store images in the folder?

Comment: Yes - there is only 1 button in the form and it is not a standard `submit` button, it is a simple `button` so it does not submit the form as such but is used to trigger the javascript code.

Comment: I am so confused. Then how can I send uploaded images if there is no submit button?

Comment: The images are sent by javascript ( ajax )

Comment: Is there no other way? Because I see the code is too long. Other than that there also does not use submit. I think just need some code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144839/discussion-between-ramraider-and-moses-toh).